# Permutations / probability question about color arrangements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There are 12 colored balls: 6 red, 4 blue, 1 green, and 1 yellow. The balls of the same color don’t have any differences.

(a) If all the balls are put in a row, how many possible arrangements are there?

(b) If one of the arrangements in part (a) is randomly selected, what is the probability
that no two red balls are next to each other?

So I solved part a) and found that 12!/6!4!1!1! is the number of arrangements.
However, I am struggling with part b) but I think I've got most of it figured out:

There are 7 arrangements where the red balls don't touch, ex:

R_R_R_R_R_R_

_R_R_R_R_R_R

R__R_R_R_R_R

[...]

We are concerned about 2 adjacent red balls, the 4 remaining red balls, and the 6 other balls of color, which is 12 positions. So, would the probability of such arrangement perhaps be 7!/4!1!1! ? My answer seems a bit off, not sure where to restart though. Any help?

Comment: There are ${12 \choose 6}=924$ overall equally likely ways of positioning the $R$s, of which your $7$ are satisfactory.  So the probability is $\frac 7{924}$ - which can be simplified

Comment: What you calculated is not the probability.  It is the number of favorable cases.  If you divide by your answer to the first part, you will obtain the correct probability.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of Henry provides the elegant approach.  The alternative approach that you attempted is analyzed as follows:

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$

where

$$D = \binom{12}{6} \times \binom{6}{4} \times \binom{2}{1} = (924) \times (15 \times 2).$$

You accurately identified the $(7)$ distinct ways that the red balls can be placed.  For each such way, there are $(6 \times 5 = 30)$ ways of selecting which of the $(6)$ remaining slots will get a green ball, and then (after that) which of the $(5)$ remaining slots will get a yellow ball.

Note that once the positions of the red, green and yellow balls are set, the distribution is completely determined.  That is, the remaining open slots all are assigned a blue ball.

Therefore,

$$N = 7 \times (6 \times 5).$$

Therefore, the probability equals

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{7 \times (6 \times 5)}{924 \times (15 \times 2)} = \frac{7}{924} = \frac{1}{132}.$$